# SSRS 2008 R2 - MAX TABS on an export to Excel

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

When I export a SSRS report to excel, page breaks are made into excel tabs.  Is there a limit to the maximum tabs that can be created via this export?

I know there are row/column limitations but was not sure about tabs/page-breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit of sheets in a workbook depends on the computer memory.

[Look at this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)

There is no different in exporting.